# Boosting the relevance score based on the unique keyword found

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am in a scenario where I need to give more relevance to the document in Index if it has a unique keyword. Let me provide a scenario.
Let's say I need to search for a term **znkdref unsuccessfull** so the result will have contents which have **znkdref** or **unsuccessfull** or **znkdref unsuccessfull** but here I want that the contents which are having **znkdref unsuccessfull** should have highest relevance and then content having **znkdref** should have less relevance and then content having **unsuccessfull** should have least relevance.

Is there a way to achieve this ?? I would be glad to get any help

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Query Time Boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html#query-time-boosting), in particular [Prioritized Clauses](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-query-strings.html#prioritising-clauses).

In short you need to extract the keywords that you want boosted and build a query that boosts the parts that you want.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "match": {  
                "content": {
                    "query":    "znkdref",
                    "boost":    2
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "match": {  
                "content": {
                    "query":    "unsuccessfull"               
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
}
```

**Update based on comment:**

If you want to know why a document got the score that it did (maybe to identify "keywords") then you can pass in "explain" as a query parameter or set it in the root POST payload. The result will now have document frequency counts and sub scores.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this doesn't explain my need. The above condition is just an example, the main question as Elasticsearch has its own feature of IDF. So can we leverage the same feature. Because we don't know what will be the keyword to be searched. Will we be able to distinguish the unique keyword using Elasticsearch.

Comment: I see, that wasn't clear to me. I updated my answer to include an aside about using the explain feature.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "znkdref" is a unique keyword?  For example, "znkdref" is a special name of something. If so.

- Of course, the documents match the whole query string "znkdref unsuccessfull" will have a highest relevance score in general.
- The documents contain "znkdref" will usually have a higher relevance score than the documents contain "unsuccessfull". Because TF.IDF score of "znkdref" is bigger than TF.IDF score of "unsuccessfull".

The relevance score function is described at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html

I hope that my answer is helpful for you.